# Why system becomes unresponsive before system reach total memory

Tags: linux, memory, freeze, unresponsive

Why the system becomes unresponsive before system total memory be reached ?

I've 2G DDR3 installed (1802MB usable) but when memory usage reach ~1450MB the system starts to be unresponsive and stay freezing until the memory usage reduce.

```
% uname -r
3.14.11-1-lts

% free -m
              total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          1802       1614        187        147        189        301
-/+ buffers/cache:       1123        679
Swap:         1023        206        817
```

To monitor memory usage I'm using a awesome wm widget.

Swap read speeds:

```
 % sudo hdparm -tT /dev/sda5

 /dev/sda5:
 Timing cached reads:   3958 MB in  2.00 seconds = 1979.41 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads: 130 MB in  3.02 seconds =  43.03 MB/sec
```

Swap write speeds (not swap to be precise, but write speed to disk partition):

```
 # dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda5 bs=8k count=500000
 54587+0 records in
 54587+0 records out
 447176704 bytes (447 MB) copied, 7.81582 s, 57.2 MB/s
```

Comment: Take a look at the system log. If the OOM killer is active, the system is in trouble. Otherwise, the swap is probably slow as hell.

Comment: Your system become slow because your swap is using 206MB.  This is to be expected.

Comment: @DanielB I don't know how to check if OOM killer is active. I've updated question with swap partition speeds.

Comment: @Ramhound your comment make no sense to me, since the swap resides in disk, how can this affect memory usage ? can you explain your comment please.

Comment: Read speeds for swap are only 1 part, what are the write speeds like?

Comment: @cybernard updated question.

Comment: Swap = virtual memory = physical memory

Comment: You'll know it when the OOM killer strikes. ;) Still, that speed is horrible, and it's even a linear test. What kind of stone age drive is that?

Comment: @DanielB its a... http://ix.io/dsw